# Avoid complete page flickering using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flicker, client-side-scripting

The following code causes the whole page to flicker:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    console.log("whole page dissapears here");
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: 0});
    queryTimer = setInterval(heavyFlicker(), 500);      
});

function heavyFlicker () {
    clearInterval(queryTimer);
    if (acc < 10) {
        var searchURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/index.php/searchPart?processName=' + 
            processName + '&searchField=' + searchField + '&searchValue=' + searchValue + '&searchPos=' + searchPos;

        console.log('no ajax, no flickering:' + acc);
        $.ajax({
            url: searchURL,
            dataType : "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (searchResults) {
                console.log("success");
                acc++;
                queryTimer = setInterval(heavyFlicker(), 500);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error");
                acc = 11;
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("whole page reappears here");
    }
}
```

I thought that the flicker happened because I was modifying the page dynamically (adding rows to a table), but then I found out the flicker occurs by the mere call to `$.ajax()`. If I comment it out, there is no flicker.

Tried both on Safari and Chrome, Windows and Mac. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are `queryTimer` and `acc` declared/initialised?

Comment: What are you actually *trying to do*? If calling `heavyFlicker()` causes heavy flickering, everything seems to be fine? What is wrong? What did you expect?

Comment: You need to *pass* a function to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval), not call the function immediately and pass the result. Omit the parenthesis!

Comment: `queryTimer` and `acc` are just global (window) variables, like `var queryTimer;`. Omitting the function parenthesis when setting the timer changes nothing. I'm invoking a backend incremental search routine which returns a json object with search results. I want to display these results as the search progresses. BTW, everything works as expected, except for the page blinking at each call.

Answer (score 2):

There was an empty document ready function in an include file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

I removed this and everything worked as expected.